# mysql sum only producing 1

Tags: python, mysql, sum

[image]

I've looking around for a solution but can't seem to spot what I' doing wrong. I have a mysql database with a table with 2 columns: clock (contains a timestamp), and state (either contains 1 or 0). When a button is pressed on my breadboard (I am using a raspberry pi), 1 is entered into the database which updates continually, and if the button is not being pressed, 0 is entered into the table. This works as I have selecting the table in command line and the appropriate number of 1's and 0's are displayed.

In a seperate python file, the database and table are called and supposedly a sum of the state column is taken, and if this is 1 or more, I know the button has been pressed in the last 30 seconds as the table will clear every 30 seconds.

The issue is that however many 1's and 0's, and even when the table is empty, the sum only returns 1. I am very new to python so this error could be embarrisingly small, thanks for your help all the same!

Here is the entire python file for the sum:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLDB.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'sensordb')
cur = conn.cursor()

but1 = cur.execute("SELECT SUM(state) FROM button1")
print "%d" % but1
```

Comment: Show the table's schema and data.

Comment: ive added the schema and its empty at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the row as well.

```
cur.execute("SELECT SUM(state) FROM button1")
row = cur.fetchone()

    while row is not None:
        print(row)
        row = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: If this answer helped you,  please accept and up vote.  Thank you @joshmh

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there....

After the cur.execute(....)

You then need to read the output...

```
for result in cursor.execute("Your QUERY"):
  if result.with_rows:
    print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(
      result.statement))
    print(result.fetchall())
```

Hope this helps you....